# Did NASA just broke the world record for fastest aircraft by going over 10 times faster than the previous record?

Tags: helicopter, nasa

The current world record is held by the Lockheed SR-71 Blackbird. In 1976, this aircraft reached a top speed of 3,529.6 km/h, according to Wikipedia.

Fast forward 44 years, and NASA just launched the Perseverance mission to Mars, which includes the Ingenuity helicopter. This helicopter will perform the first extraterrestrial flight ever. In order to get to Mars, the rover and the helicopter will be accelerated to a relative velocity of 39,887.5 km/h (or 24,785 mph, according to SpaceFlightNow).

Even though Ingenuity is not reaching this velocity by means of its own propulsion, it is still an aircraft traveling at almost 40,000 km/h. So one could argue that it broke the speed record for fastest aircraft ever.

The Fédération Aéronautique Internationale set up specific rules for official aviation records. Will this one count?

Comment: This is ridiculous. The speed of about 40,000 km/h is reached by the rocket **in space**. Speed is relative in space, so you have to define with respect to what this speed is measured. You could define any arbitrary reference frame and reach arbitrarily high speeds (as long as they stay below speed of light). I highly doubt the Fédération Aéronautique Internationale will count this...

Comment: The Shuttle would have broken the SR-71 record by reaching orbital velocity, if "in space" counted.

Comment: SR-71 holds the record for the fastest air-breathing intra-atmospheric aircraft. However, the record for the fastest aircraft inside the atmosphere was the rocket powered X-15. Space is an entirely different thing. Even the International Space Station orbits at 17,100 mph (27,600 km/h)

Comment: We are all flying through space.

Answer (score 4):

Doubtful. Aviation speed records are relative to the air or ground relative to the body they are flying. Ingenuity is currently a passenger on a spacecraft, it's not under its own power, it isn't flying and didn't do anything to get itself to the speed it is at. Once it is on Mars it will certainly be a record breaker, but that's when it's actually flying.